# If $F$ is a function symbol with arity $2$, then is $F(x,F(x,F(x,x)))$ a term?

Tags: predicate-logic

Here $F$ is a function symbol with arity $2$.

The solutions say it is but I am not sure.

If $F$ has arity $2$, but the first $F$ on the outside contains three arguments: $x$, $F(x)$ and $F(x,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful to use lower-case letters : $f, g,\ldots$ for *function* symbols and upper-case letters : $P, R,\ldots$ for *predicate* symbols.

---

The first one is the recursive **Defintion** of *term* :

*i)* every (individual) *variable* : $x_1, x_2,\ldots$ is a term

*ii)* every *constant* : $c_1, c_2,\ldots$ is a term

*iii)* if $f_i^n$ is a *function* symbol with arity $n$ (i.e. an $n$-ary function symbol) and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are terms, then :

> > $f_i^n(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is a term.

In the last case, we have to take care of arity (the "exponent" $n$ of $f_i^n$); often it is left unspecified, because we can "read it" form the context.

In the language of *arithmetic*, $+$ (the "sum") and $\times$ (the "product") are both *binary* function symbols. In this cases, we usually "switch" form the "formal" way of writing : $+(x,y)$ (the "prefix" notation) to the "informal" one : $x+y$ (the "infix" notation).

A *term* denotes an "object" of the domain of discourse; thus, a function symbol allows us to build "complex" terms from already defined ones.

For example, $0+1$ (i.e. the "infomal" way of writing : $+(0,1)$) is a term built form the function symbol $+$ and the two individual constants $0,1$. The individual constants denote the corersponding nutural numbers : *zero* and *one*, and the "complex" term will denote the number *one*.

---

Having defined *terms*, we need the recursive **Defintion** of *formula* :

*Note* : in *first-order* logic, we usually use the binary symbol $=$ (*identity*) as a logical symbol.

*i)* if $t_1, t_2$ are *terms*, then $t_1=t_2$ is an *atomic* formula;

*ii)* if $R_i^n$ is a *predicate* symbol with arity $n$ and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are terms, then :

> > $R_i^n(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is an *atomic* formula.

Also in this case we have to take care of arity (the "exponent" $n$ of $R_i^n$); often it is left unspecified, because we can "read it" form the context.

*iii)* If $\varphi, \varphi_1, \varphi_2$ are formulae, then :

> > $\lnot \varphi, \varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2, \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2, \varphi_1 \rightarrow \varphi_2, \varphi_1 \leftrightarrow \varphi_2$ are formulae

*iv)* If $\varphi$ is a formula and $x$ is a variable, then :

> > $\exists x \varphi, \forall x \varphi$ are formulae.

Consider again the *first-order* language (with : $=$) of arithmetic, with individual *constants* : $0,1$, function symbols : $+, \times$ and (binary) predicate symbol : $<$ .

The following are examples of *atomic* formulae :

> > $x=x, 0=1, 0 < 1$.

The following are examples of formulae :

> > $\forall x (x=x), \lnot (0=1), \exists x (x < 1), \forall x (0 < x \lor 0 = x)$.

---

Consider now your examples :

*a)* $f(x,f(x,f(x,x)))$

and use the binary function symbol $+$ in place of $f$. We get :

> $+(x,+(x,+(x,x)))$, i.e. $(x + (x + (x + x)))$.

It is a **term**, because it satisfy the definition of term above : $x+x$ is a term (built up from the binary function symbol $+$ and two terms, two occurrences of the variable $x$; thus also $x + (x + x)$ is a term, and so on..

Consider now :

*b)* $f(x,y)=x$ where $f$ is a function symbol with arity $2$,

and use again the the binary function symbol $<$ in place of $f$. We get :

> $+(x,y)=x$, i.e. $(x+y)=x$.

$x$ is a term, and also $x+y$ is; thus, according to the above definition of *formula*, it is an atomic formula, because it is built up with the binary symbol $=$ for identity and two terms.

Finally :

*c)* If $P$ is a predicate symbol with arity $1$, according to the above definition of formula, $P(x)$ is an *atomic* formula ($x$ is a term).

In the language of arithmetic, we can define a (unary) predicate $Even$ such that $Even(n)$ holds if $n$ is an *even* number (but in this case, the predicate $Even$ is "formally" an abbreviation for a "complex" formula like : $\exists z (x=z \times (1+1))$, and thus $Even(x)$ is a formula, but it is not an atomic one).

---

Next we have the **Definition** of the set $Sub(\varphi)$ of *subformulae* of a formula $\varphi$ :

*i)* if $\varphi$ is atomic, then the set of subformuale of $\varphi$ is $Sub(\varphi) = \{ \varphi \}$;

*ii)* $Sub(\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2) = Sub(\varphi_1) \cup Sub(\varphi_2) \cup \{ \varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2 \}$, and the same for the other binary connectives;

*iii)* $Sub(\lnot \varphi) = Sub(\varphi) \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$;

*iv)* $Sub(\forall x \varphi) = Sub(\varphi) \cup \{ \forall x \varphi \}$, and the same for $\exists$.

We say that $\psi$ is a *subformula* of $\varphi$ if $\psi \in Sub(\varphi)$.

An example in the language of arithmetic can be :

> $\forall x (0 = x \lor 0 < x)$;

its subformulae are $\forall x (0 = x \lor 0 < x)$ itself, $(0 = x \lor 0 < x), 0 = x$ and $0 < x$.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and detailed answer

Comment: Its ok if you dont want to but could you do the same thing with the definitions of subformulae please with an example?

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment, but I can't still comment)

The first F on the outside contains TWO arguments: x and F(x,F(x,x)).

The first F of F(x,F(x),F(x,x)) would contain three arguments, but you would not be allowed to write that because, the second F would have one argument, and the third, two arguments. But either F has one, two or three arguments.
F(x,G(x),H(x,x)) would work.

Comment: It looks like ananswer to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a term. The first argument of the outermost $F$ contains the two arguments $x$ and $F(x,F(x,x))$.